# ImageDataGenerator in Keras using flow_from_dataframe

Tags: python, validation, machine-learning, keras, dataset

I have a dataset of images whose names are stored in the first column of a CSV file and the target labels are stored in the second column. I am trying to generate training and validation data using the flow_from_dataframe method. This is how my data generation part of the code looks like -

```
datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.,validation_split = 0.2)

#creating training generator
train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=train_data,
directory="Images/",
x_col="UID",
y_col="growth_stage",
subset="training",
batch_size=100,
seed=1,
shuffle=True,
class_mode="sparse",
target_size=(100,100))

# creating validation generator
val_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=train_data,
directory="Images/",
x_col="UID",
y_col="growth_stage",
subset="validation",
batch_size=100,
seed=1,
shuffle = True,
class_mode="sparse",
target_size=(100,100))
```

Here's the output -

```
Found 4888 validated image filenames belonging to 7 classes.
Found 1222 validated image filenames belonging to 7 classes.
```

Now if I try to see what's inside my val_generator, I observe that there are only two types of label values. Here is the code I used to access the values stored in my val_generator -

```
b = val_generator[0][1]
print(b)
```

which gives the result  -

```
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 1. 0.]
```

From my understanding, there should be 7(=number of classes) types of values instead of just 0's and 1's?
Also if I increase my validation_split to 0.5, `print(b)` results in -

```
[0. 2. 1. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 3. 1. 0. 0. 3. 3. 3. 3. 0. 1. 0. 2. 1. 0. 2.
 2. 2. 1. 0. 1. 3. 0. 2. 1. 3. 0. 0. 1. 1. 2. 3. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 3. 0.
 1. 3. 2. 1. 1. 0. 2. 0. 0. 0. 2. 0. 1. 2. 0. 2. 3. 3. 1. 0. 0. 2. 0. 3.
 1. 2. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 3. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 2. 2. 0. 3. 1. 3. 2. 1. 2. 1.
 0. 1. 2. 1.]
```

Can anyone please help me in understanding what's happening here and how to fix this problem?

Comment: That is for a single batch, you specified the batch_size to be 100.